# I want to create a popup window with three buttons after submitting a form. How do i do that?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form at `addCharger.php`, so when I click on the submit button, I want a popup window to come out, with three buttons likes:

1. Ok
2. Add Similar
3. Add Different

So if I click on 'Add Similar' button on the popup window opens, it will direct me to `addSimilarCharger.php` and on that page I need the same values as the previous one in the form so I can add another charger.

If I click on 'Add Different' then it will direct me back to `addCharger.php`.If I click on 'Ok' then it will direct me to another page.

Answer (score 1):

What Kasma is saying its true: but if you want to use jquery you have to download Jquery plugins on your pc and link to them or put this line in your head tags  . but u need to be online always if u using that link . so start with small jquery fade in programs u will understand it and u will be able to do what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

1. Send data using ajax of form 
   [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
2. on successful, pop up window using jquery dialog or any other moal dialog plugin
   [link](http://www.queness.com/post/1696/create-a-beautiful-looking-custom-dialog-box-with-jquery-and-css3)
3. perform action based on your requirement

Comment: Sorry i've not learnt ajax and jquery before and i don't really understand the links you've given me, is there other simpler methods to do this? If not, would you like to explain further on how i can use ajax and jquery? Thank you!